# AsyncTask not receiving calling activity context

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm getting the error message "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.

Yes, I know this error is all over stackoverflow and it's based on not getting the context of the activity... however, I am pulling that context and still receiving the error.

From MainActivity:

> new MemberStream(this).execute();

From MemberStream:
>

```
public HomeActivity activity;
ProgressDialog dialog;

public MemberStream(HomeActivity a) {
    this.activity = a;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(a.getApplicationContext());
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    this.dialog.show();
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    updateMembers(url, 0);
    return true;
}
```

When I run the application, I get the preceding error on

> dialog = new ProgressDialog(a.getApplicationContext());

Any ideas?

Comment: dialog = new ProgressDialog(a); try this. you already have a activity context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Activity activity;
ProgressDialog dialog;

public MemberStream(Activity a) {
    this.activity = a;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(a);
}
```

You alread have a context object (Your activity)

Answer (score 1):

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(a);
```

You already have a activity context passed to the asynctask constructor.

To know when to use activity context and when to use application context check the link below and answer by commonsware

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public Context context ;
ProgressDialog dialog;

public MemberStream(Context c) {
    context = c;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
}
```